# for loop append variable bash 6

Tags: bash

I have this script, and i have multiple results.

How can the multiple results be output in one variable?

Example: results from first loop is English, second loop is Italian.

I need final Results in a Variable : English Italian

```
for i in $(ls -l $1/$2/);do
if [[ $i =~ .*\.idx$ ]];then
    tr -d '\r' < $1/$2/$i > $1/$2/newfile
    rm -f $1/$2/$i
    mv $1/$2/newfile $1/$2/$i
    results=$(cat $1/$2/$i |awk '/^# alt:/ { a[$3] } END { for (l in a) { printf("%s%s", c, l); c = " " } printf("\n") }')
    echo "Results for $i : $results"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, just accumulate your results in another variable:

```
RESULTS=""
for i in $(ls -l $1/$2/);do
if [[ $i =~ .*\.idx$ ]];then
    tr -d '\r' < $1/$2/$i > $1/$2/newfile
    rm -f $1/$2/$i
    mv $1/$2/newfile $1/$2/$i
    results=$(cat $1/$2/$i |awk '/^# alt:/ { a[$3] } END { for (l in a) { printf("%s%s", c, l); c = " " } printf("\n") }')
    RESULTS="$RESULTS$results "
fi
done
echo ${RESULTS%" "}  #Get rid of the trailing space
```

Comment: See [useless use of cat](https://superuser.com/questions/323060/what-is-the-general-consensus-on-useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all results in a single variable if you use the following syntax:

```
variable=$(command)
```

You might find it useful to put your code in a function and then call it like this:

```
function command() {

# your code from above 

}

results=$( command "$@" )
```